# NSWindowController sends all input to main window for processing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating and showing an `NSWindow,` which happens to be my preferences menu, through a custom method:

```
- (void)openPreferencesWindow{
    if (![self.windowController isWindowLoaded]){
        self.windowController = [[CCPreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"];
    }
    [[self.windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

This works fine, however the window has text fields in it which are sending all key presses to the main window, which then deals with them according to my actions in IB. To clarify:

1. I call `openPreferencesWindow:`
2. I press the left arrow key while the preferences menu is open
3. My main window registers this arrow press, and calls the `leftArrow:` method, thus updating the main window which is no longer the key window

I figured making the new window the firstResponder or keyWindow would work, and not send all input over to the main window:

```
[self.windowController window] makeFirstResponder:self.windowController];
```

Except anything typed while the preference window is key is still processed by the main window. How do I make the preference menu process all inputs on its own, and not have the main window respond to them?

---

AppDelegate.m

```
@property (strong) CCPreferencesController *windowController;

...

- (void)promptUserToLogin{
    ...
    [self openPreferencesWindow];
}

- (void)openPreferencesWindow{
    if (![self.windowController isWindowLoaded]){
        self.windowController = [[CCPreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"];
    }
    [[self.windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

CCPreferencesController.h

```
@interface CCPreferencesController : NSWindowController {}
...
```

CCPreferencesController.m

```
- (id)init{
    if(self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"]) {}
    return self;
}
```

PreferenceMenu.xib

1. The File's Owner class is "CCPreferencesController"
2. The Window's referencing outlet is File's Owner

MainMenu.xib

1. A Menu Item's sent action is an IBAction which calls `openPreferencesWindow'

Comment: Could you clarify your object hierarchy again? what type is your root view, self?

Comment: @MattyAyOh Clarify it in what ways? And I believe so. There are still holes (obviously) in my Cocoa/Obj-C knowledge...

Comment: Er what type is your self

Comment: @MattyAyOh What's the best way to check? If I log just `self` it returns `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Oh okay gotcha, you're in your appdelegate.  are you creating your views programmatically, or through IB (interface builder, nib/xib/storyboards)?

Comment: I created the view with IB, and display it programmatically.

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  So in your appdelegate you added the windowcontroller property (of type CCPreferencesController), and bound it to your xib.  So in your CCPreferencesController, go to your window outlet and make sure that it is correctly bound to the window in your xib (on the left of the line the circle should be filled in)

Comment: @MattyAyOh If I open up PreferenceMenu.xib, the window is bound to the File Owner's window.

Comment: Is your File Owner CCPreferencesController?  Go to the identity inspector on the right, and look at "Class" sorry this is taking a bit, I'm not 100% sure what you're problem is so I'm kind of running through options

Comment: @MattyAyOh I appreciate the help. And yes, it is CCPreferencesController.

Comment: Also, when you look at the bindings and see File's Owner, on the left side of that connection it should have the name of the outlet.  What is that?

Comment: Okay hmm... so do you have a CCPreferencesController.h file?

Comment: @MattyAyOh I do. [Let's talk about it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61137/discussion-between-charlie-and-mattyayoh).

Comment: @MattyAyOh Still haven't figured it out...

Comment: can you post an actual working sample (complete with nibs)? that code you posted isnt enough to replicate this issue.

Comment: @BradAllred I updated with relevant code...

Comment: I tried replicating your issue as was not able. obviously something in your nib or `CCPreferencesController ` is screwed up.

Comment: @BradAllred What do you suggest I do?

Comment: post a minimal project that has this issue. I wonder if you are overriding something in your controller subclass.

Comment: @BradAllred [Here's a working example](http://cl.ly/261y0q2D3J15) (press the arrow keys while the preference window is both opened and closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the sample project you posted and come to the following conclusion:

This behavior is expected (I think) you have arrow keys set to be a menu shortcut, so they are triggering that menu action (NextImage and PreviousImage).

I have verified that if these menu items are disabled, then the arrow keys function normally in the preferences window.

You ought to be able to use cocoa bindings to disable those menu items when the main window is not in focus. Try binding to the window with `isKeyWindow` or `keyWindow` (AFIK this was an undocumented binding so it may no longer work).

You can bind to a KVO compliant property (or even KVO path into properties of their properties) of *any* object in the nib (AppController, Windows, etc) through IB.

You can also assign bindings at *runtime* if the object you wish to bind with is not in your nib or doesnt exist until later in the lifecycle (use `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`; besure to also `unbind`).

All that is required is that the property is KVO compliant which `@synthesized` properties are, and any other dynamic property can be if you use `willChangeValuForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`. See apples [Cocoa Bindings documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) (which has links to KVC/KVO documentation).

An couple of alternatives to enabling/disabling menu items that you may like better:

1. Assign a modifier to be used with the arrow key such as <kbd>Command</kbd>
2. Handle the   <kbd>←</kbd>  keys inside whatever control/window those menu items are bound to (by overriding `keyDown:` and/or `keyUp:`) and remove the keyboard shortcuts for those menu items.

Edit2: [here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976298/cocoa-validate-menu-items-in-multiple-windows) about how to enable/disable menuitems based on the keyWindow, including the use of cocoa bindings for it.

Comment: Bindings didn't work, but having to manually enable and then re-enable items seems superfluous. Is there any other way to streamline it?

Comment: @Charlie, I have updated my answer with more info on bindings and some alternatives.